# Remove/hide content if it would appear as an orphan

Tags: page-breaking, widows-orphans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prevent “action” if top of page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61627/prevent-action-if-top-of-page)

I have some blocks of text, separated by a `\hline`.  Because the LaTeX code is generated automatically from user-entered data, sometimes the `\hline` appears last on the page, and sometimes it appears first.

Since the `\hline` is only used to provide a clear division between blocks, it's not needed last or first on the page, since the page break itself provides the division.  Is it possible to hide/ignore/delete the `\hline` if it would be the first or last element on the page?

Here is some example code to illustrate the issue:

```
\vspace{20cm} % Adjust as necessary
\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}
\hline
\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}
\hline
\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `\leaders` you can define a rule that will "disappear" at the beginning of a page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=7cm,textwidth=18cm]{geometry}% just for the example

\newcommand\Myrule{%
  \par\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt\par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3.64cm} % Adjust as necessary

\noindent\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}
\Myrule
\noindent\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}
\Myrule
\noindent\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}
\Myrule
\noindent\parbox[t]{3cm}{Example:}\parbox[t]{15cm}{This is an example}

\end{document}
```

[image]