# Vertical bar appearing except on top of page

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core

I want a command `\shybar` which prints a `\textbar` *except* if it would be the first character on the page. In this case, it should do nothing. Because of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61627/prevent-action-if-top-of-page), I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand*\shybar{\leaders{\mbox\textbar}}

\begin{document}
\shybar This bar should not be printed, but \shybar this one should.
\end{document}
```

I inserted an `\mbox` because `\leaders` asked for a box. Anyway, it did not work; it still asks for boxes. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is no concept for *the first character on a page*. As far as typesetting paragraphs is concerned, you should imagine them printed on a a long scroll of paper, so there's no way (at least with standard TeX) to have `\shybar` to disappear if it is inside a paragraph and it happens to be the first item on the first line on a new page: paragraphs are typeset *before* page break decision are made.

Comment: Well, too bad then... :-)

Comment: Maybe something can be done with LuaTeX. Can you tell *why* you'd like to do this?

Comment: you CAN tell if a character is the first in a paragraph using \ifvmode.

Comment: @egreg I'm converting an XML document (of a classical piece of literature) to LaTeX. `\shybar` is used to mark a page skip in the *original* publication. What I want to do is to write `\shybar\marginpar{227}` to mark page 227.

Comment: @Gaussler I don't understand why you want it to disappear, then

Comment: @JohnKormylo I looked into `\ifvmode`, but I don't see exactly how it can be used. Can you show me? :-)

Comment: @egreg Because it also appears in headers and at similar places where it does not look pretty.

Comment: I tried to use atbegshi and tikzpagenodes to delay drawing the \textbars until \AtBeginShipout, but the bars got drawn on the next page.  Interestingly, they showed up in the right spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me that `\tikz[remember page,overlay]` must already wait until the page is laid out in order to work right.  Nor will it change the layout since it overlays the existing text.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newlength{\tempx}
\newlength{\tempy}

\newcommand*\shybar{\ifvmode\tikz[remember picture,overlay]% start of paragraph
{\pgfextracty{\tempy}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{north west}}}%
\ifdim\tempy<\baselineskip\relax%
\else\pgftext[base]{\textbar};\fi}%
\else\tikz[remember picture,overlay]% inside paragraph
{\let\p1=\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpointanchor{current page text area}{north west}}%
\pgfextractx{\tempx}{\p1}%
\pgfextracty{\tempy}{\p1}%
\ifdim\tempy<\baselineskip \ifdim\tempx=0pt \relax%
\else\pgftext[base]{\textbar};\fi%
\else\pgftext[base]{\textbar};\fi}\fi%
\hspace*{1pt}}% reserve space

\begin{document}
\shybar This bar should not be printed, but \shybar this one should.

\rule{1pt}{7.1in}

Last line of page\newline
\shybar This bar should not be printed, but \shybar this one should.
\end{document}
```

This approach has a problem with things like hanging indentation.