# Execute some code at the beginning of each page: how to do it in my case?

Tags: macros, atbegshi

I use an environment for my exercises that draw an horizontal rule before each exercise.

I would like to prevent the rule to be drawn if the exercise is at the beginning of a page.

I use a variable `\isFirstExercise` and I tried to play with `\AtBeginShipout` and `\AtBeginningPage` but it does not work.

Can you help me achieving this?

---

See the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a5paper}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{bophook}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\def\varIsNewPageExercise{1}
\newenvironment{exercise}
{\begin{samepage}\if\varIsNewPageExercise1\else\medskip\hrule\medskip\fi\nopagebreak\textbf{Exercise}\par\nopagebreak}
{\end{samepage}\global\let\varIsNewPageExercise=0}

\AtBeginShipout{\global\let\varIsNewPageExercise=1}
\AtBeginPage{\global\let\varIsNewPageExercise=1}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
$1+1 = 2$ \\
$2+2 = 4$ 
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61643/2388

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. How I can force `\disappearingrule` to be "glued" to the Exercise? In some case, the `\disappearingrule` of an exercise is printed at the end of the page and the exercise is on the next page.